# Unity Button not working/highlighting/interacting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I have made the program so that, once the level is done, a panel will pop up and this button is attached. However this button is not working.

I have - Checked my eventsystem, Checked Raycast Settings, Set the onclick event, Also brought the button out on the z axis so that it would have no interference from the panel.

My Hierarchy

[image]

Button's Inspector

[image]

Canvas' Inspector

[image]

Comment: On Canvas the order in which the elements appear MATTER. Make sure there are no panels or full-screen size images below (in the hierarchy) of the button, in practice, everything that is static should be on top while everything that is interactable should be on the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

It's because you original color of the `Image` is completely black. The `Button` component just tries to tint the original color, but because it's black, you see no effect.

Oh, and... As @Glurth said, you have enabled `Block Raycast` on the `CanvasGroup`, so basiclly the `Button` doesn't even receive pointer events.

Comment: I changed the colours of the button and changed the blocked raycast to off and still no change.

Comment: Do you have `EventSystem` component in your hierarchy? It is responsible for dispatching events to UI elements

Comment: Yeah its in the hierarchy like you can see in the picture. Still not working

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen it. Silly me... `EventSystem` does it's work if it is in the scene. You will see it once button starts getting the events. One more guess, try changing `Blocking objects` and `Blocking mask` to `Everything` on the `Graphic Raycaster` component. I'll have to check this situation once I'll get back home. By the way, you have disabled `Block Raycast` on the `Canvas Group`, right?

Comment: I changed blocking mask and blocking objects to everything but still arent getting anything, and i do have block raycast disabled

Comment: My last idea is to try increasing alpha channel of `Normal` tint inside `Button` component. Then try changing tint colors to various different colors, like red, blue and so on, to see if the button is actually getting any action. If there's no response, try looking at the code to see if you are not setting some of raycast associated parameters (like `Block Raycast` and `Interactable`, etc.) manually. If that's not the case, maybe some invisible image is hovering over the button and it intercepts the pointer event...

Answer (score 0):

I see you have "Blocks Raycasts" configured for the Canvas group, which you have added to the canvas itself.

I don't think this component is supposed to go on the canvas itself anyway;  it's intended to allow one to disable or hide groups of objects on your canvas.  The "blocks raycasts" is intended to prevent clicking on controls that are behind this group, and collect clicks for the group itself.  If you put everything on your canavas in this group, it will collect all the clicks for everything.

Comment: I have tried disabling Blocks Raycasts and also changed the order of the objects so that the intractable is at the bottom, yet still no function.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, i had 'ignore parent groups' unchecked which did not allow the mouse pointer to recognise the button as it was a 'child' of canvas

Thankyou all for your help!

[My Canvas Inspector component, Canvas Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIuyr.png)